# Не пойму как сократить запись

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main() {
    var s = 0.0

    for (i in 1..10){

        s+=Math.pow(-1.0, i.toDouble())*(i+1) / (1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10)
    }
    print(s)
}
```

Как нибудь можно сократить запись 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10 ?

Задача решить уравнение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ``Math.pow(x, y)`` это уже не котлин. На новокотлинском это будет ``x.pow(y)``. В данном случае ``(-1.0).pow(i)``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас формула не совсем верно реализована. Верно будет так

```
int fact = 1;
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    fact *= i;
    s += Math.pow(-1d, i) * (i + 1) / fact;
}
```